# How to fix cannot convert from int[] to int

Tags: android, image, int

i have following code in my project

```
ImageView lifesimage, good;
TextView lifes1;

int gamelifes=6, gamehints=6, index=0; 
int [] heartimage={R.drawable.lifessix,
                   R.drawable.lifesfive,
                   R.drawable.lifesfour,
                   R.drawable.lifesthree,
                   R.drawable.lifestwo,
                   R.drawable.lifesone,
                   R.drawable.lifesno,
                   };

    good=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.youwin);

    lifesimage =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lifes);
    lifesimage.setImageResource(heartimage[0]);

    lifes1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lifestext);
    lifes1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    lifes1.setText(String.valueOf(gamelifes));
```

So if the answer is correct or wrong Then the code is

```
 if(you.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[index]))
            {                   
                good.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {    
                heartimage++;                    
                gamelifes--;
                lifes1.setText(String.valueOf(gamelifes));
            }
```

but I found some error on `heartimage++;` such as *Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int*
how to fix this code? is there a function that can make the image appear sequential ?

Comment: you have to use a count variable to increase the value of int. Just like int n;
n++; heartimage[n]

Comment: it is not C and heartimage is not a pointer ...

Comment: @Deepak Goyal You mean like the function of  index?

Comment: @Ricci yes, just like the function of index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'heartimage' in your code is an integer array, and you are trying to add 1 to it... not going to work. Create a new variable 'index' (or whatever you would like to name it) that will store the current index of the heart value that you want.

Then lifesimage.setImageResource(heartimage[index]);